# Convert Rows to Columns in MySQL for custom values

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have gone through a lot of similar questions(row to column conversion in mysql) and solutions provided for the same but those solutions were not working for me!

Expected Result:

```
Name |S1   |S2   |S3   |S4   |S5   |S6
----------------------------------------
ABC  |Pass |Fail |Fail |Pass |Pass |Fail


SQL Query:
----------

SELECT Name,
 (CASE WHEN (Semester = 'S1'  AND Result= 'Pass') THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END) AS S1,
 (CASE WHEN (Semester = 'S2'  AND Result= 'Pass') THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END) AS S2,
 (CASE WHEN (Semester = 'S3'  AND Result= 'Pass') THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END) AS S3,
 (CASE WHEN (Semester = 'S4'  AND Result= 'Pass') THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END) AS S4,
 (CASE WHEN (Semester = 'S5'  AND Result= 'Pass') THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END) AS S5,
 (CASE WHEN (Semester = 'S6'  AND Result= 'Pass') THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END) AS S6
FROM pivot_example
-- GROUP BY Semester
```

SQL Output:

```
Name |S1   |S2   |S3   |S4   |S5   |S6
--------------------------------------------------
ABC  |Pass |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail
ABC  |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail
ABC  |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail
ABC  |Fail |Fail |Fail |Pass |Fail |Fail
ABC  |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail |Pass |Fail
ABC  |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail |Fail
```

Comment: You didn't follow the other examples correctly. It's supposed to be `MAX(CASE WHEN ...) AS S1` and `GROUP BY Semester`

Comment: @Barmar - I used aggregated examples( SUM, COUNT, MAX) but I still ended up with the same error as displayed in below comment!

Comment: It should be `GROUP BY Name`

Comment: You have to group by whatever is in the left column of the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) in order to produce one row, change:

```
GROUP BY Semester
```

into:

```
GROUP BY Name
```

b) for the pass/fail values it might be required to query, depending how the table looks alike.

Comment: Error: SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'pivot_example.Semester' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause

Comment: @Santosh That would only happen if you have `SELECT Semester` and `GROUP BY Name`

Comment: @Barmar also thought so, because the `GROUP BY` not necessarily requires aggregated columns - but a selected column. for the value columns it's hard to tell without having seen the table.

Comment: When doing a pivot, you always group by the column that all the other columns are pivoted attributes of.